# A question on the Sorgenfrey line

Tags: general-topology

I was reading a note on the Sorgenfrey line at [this](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/a-note-on-the-sorgenfrey-line/) web page.

In the first proof (proof A), the Sorgenfrey line is Lindelöf. So my question is, with the same structure, is $[0,1)$ with the sorgenfrey topology also Lindelöf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $[0,1)$ with the Sorgenfrey topology is Lindelöf, and the proof in Dan Ma’s Topology Blog works just as well. In fact, the Sorgenfrey line $S$ is hereditarily Lindelöf, and the same proof works; this is result B of the blog post.

Comment: When he says the open cover $\mathscr{A}$ of the Sorgenfrey line S open intervals of the form $[a, b)$, does that apply to every number in the reals?

Comment: @IvordesGreenleaf: Not necessarily. The point is that if $\mathscr{U}$ is any open cover of $S$, it has a refinement $\mathscr{R}$ consisting entirely of intervals of the form $[a,b)$, and if $\mathscr{R}$ has a countable subcover, then trivially so has $\mathscr{U}$.

Comment: Then $[0,1)$ works only because it is a countable subspace of $S$?

Comment: @IvordesGreenleaf: ??? $[0,1)$ is certainly **not** countable. And **every** subspace of $S$ is Lindelöf, by exactly the same proof.

Comment: That's what I thought, $[0,1]$ is uncountable. Just a little confused, sorry. And we just know that [0,1) is trivially a subspace of S?

Comment: @IvordesGreenleaf: Since $[0,1)$ is a subset of $S$, it certainly inherits a topology from $S$ as a subspace of $S$. And yes, it’s pretty straightforward to see that this subspaces topology is the same as the Sorgenfrey topology defined directly on $[0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your help!

Comment: @IvordesGreenleaf: You’re welcome!